# Query still running after completion

Tags: hive, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform, hue, resourcemanager

When running HiveQL queries (with TEZ Execution engine) with success in Hue on Hortonworks, the process is still marked as "Running" under "Hue Job Browser" & "Hadoop ResourceManager UI". Is it supposed to be doing this waiting for new input or is it failing to terminate?

My setup:

- HortonWorks HDP-2.3.2.9-2950 running on 3 RH Linux 7 machines
- Hue 3.9.0
- Hive  1.2.1.2.3
- Oozie 4.2.0.2.3

Comment: Which execution engine for Hive: MapReduce or TEZ? Because TEZ retains a lease on YARN containers for several seconds, to avoid unnecessary allocate/deallocate operations when executing multiple queries in sequence (cf. `tez.am.container.reuse.enabled`, `tez.am.container.idle.release-timeout-min.millis`, `tez.am.container.reuse.rack-fallback.enabled` etc. in *tez-site.xml*)

Comment: Thank you Samson! Is it possible to tune this "timeout" anywhere? (I also wrote the final answer based upon your answer)

Comment: You can change these `tez.am.container.*` properties statically, in *tez-site.xml*; or you can reset them dynamically in your Hive script e.g. `set tez.am.container.reuse.enabled =false ;` (but I'm not sure it would apply immediately to the containers already allocated, since the A.M. is already up and running)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Samson Scharfrichter:

> The TEZ execution engine retains a lease on YARN containers for
>   several seconds after query completion, to avoid unnecessary
>   allocate/deallocate operations when executing multiple queries in
>   sequence.

This will make the completed query job appear as running for some seconds after the final results have appeared in the Hive Query Frontend.

Thank you Samson Scharfrichter !

Answer (score 0):

Decreasing the timeout for `tez.session.am.dag.submit.timeout.secs` can help. Time is in sec.

```
<property>
<name>tez.session.am.dag.submit.timeout.secs</name>
<value>10</value>
</property>
```

/etc/tez-site.xml file.